# How to return a 410 error with htaccess for all *.html queries?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Some time ago, I had a problem with my server. Using a security hole at Joomla, someone created thousands of files (ending in *.html) in my website.

I've deleted all these files, but Google keep querying this files. I've already added a hundred (or more) of filenames at Google Webmaster Tools to be removed, but there are still lots of files.

What I want, is to add a rule to the `.htaccess` file to return a 410 error code when any file ending with .html is requested, EXCEPT if the filename is `google123456789abcdefg.html` (a file from google). The problem is that the html files can be in any (non-existing) folder of the webserver...

Can you help me with this problem? Because I haven't a clue about how the `.htaccess` file works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

#--exclude "/google12345.html--#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/google12345abc\.html$ [NC]
#--redirect all .html requests to 410 Gone--#
RewriteRule \.html$ - [R=410,L]
```